# Is it possible to detect in a servlet that a user is connected using VPN

Tags: servlets, vpn, jaas

I need to give users different access to specific function in web app depends on remote (VPN) or local connection.
Is it possible?

I am using a Websphere server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably have two (or one for VPN only) separate servlets for handling VPN and Local clients. And then forward the request to your current servlet with a source flag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Most VPNs give users an IP address on a separate subnet, so you should be able to tell VPN users by their ip address.